# Azure DB sync or mirror between DBs hosted in different azure accounts

Tags: azure, synchronization, azure-sql-database, mirror

I need to mirror sync two azure DBs stored in two different azure accounts (so different subscription also different azure enterprise accounts as well); the DB is Azure DB not SQL Server in azure VM.
the DBs are in the same geo area.

how can this be achieved?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer is no,you can't have mirroring between two SQLAzure databases even if they are in same region..

It seems that you are trying to keep two databases in sync which are in different regions and are under different subscriptions..This is not possible,only HA option SQLAzure supports is replication with onpremises as publisher and SQLAzure database as subscriber..

One more option you can use is Georeplication(only for premium ,last when i checked) which keeps one more database in sync, which can be in different region

Comment: this is pretty much what I have found out as well after reading lots of azure documentation. it is not possible. I'll have to build my own script that moves regularly the new rows to slave DB; fortunately this approach is ok for my case. however, for those that need more realtime mirroring you can employ ms sync framework to build your own mirroring.